# Disappearing hyperlink text in Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

[image: animated GIF showing the issue]

I have no idea why this issue is occurring, as I have previously had no issues adding links to text in this document before. I update it every year for a sports-tracking related hobby, and have never seen this issue.

If anyone could shed some light on or help me troubleshoot this issue, I would really appreciate it.

edit upon suggestion by @ale, Whenever I try and create hyperlinked text in one of my google docs, the text just becomes invisible. It appears to just be this specific document, and I don't know what happened or if I did something.

Comment: The animated GIF is great as supplemental information, but it's not helpful for vision-impaired users or those who can't or won't display images. More importantly, it's also not indexed for searching. Can you please add a test description of the problem?

Comment: I added a description as you suggested, @ale. Thank you for the idea.

Comment: I found a dumb and simple resolution. The page was bugged with copy and paste. I restarted my browser and whatever the issue was has resolved itself. I have forgotten the most important lesson - turn it off and on.

Comment: Add more details like cell formatting, addons enabled / installed, if you have macros / scripts attached to the spreadsheet, name and version of your web browser and SO. Also try using another web browser and another device both in normal and private browsing (incognito modes).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it cannot be reproduced.